# Phonegap - keyboard not showing

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have tried the following code to show the soft keyboard as soon as the app load with some help of code from this [url](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/w/page/27915465/How%20to%20show%20and%20hide%20soft%20keyboard%20in%20Android) but the soft keyboard does not show. Do not know what I am doing wrong.

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {    

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //KeyBoard keyboard = new KeyBoard(this, appView);
           // appView.addJavascriptInterface(keyboard, "KeyBoard");
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            // only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
            mgr.showSoftInput(appView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

            ((InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(appView, 0); 

         }

}
```

Comment: Where is your `appView` initialized?

Comment: @Grishu - I thought it would be automatically be done someone in the phonegap code as phonegap themselves dont show where it is initialized as far as I know. Do let me know if it needs to be.

Comment: Yes, It needs to be initialized AFAIK. If you are not aware about `appView` then you can try to take a `EditText` in your layout and then you can apply the `InputManager` method on it. Then after you'll come to know your actual issue , i think so.

Comment: Grishu - thanks a lot, I started looking around the interview for the appview after you mentioned it and its fixed now. The view is accessible as this.appView. Another thing is that it works if I only reference it after I do the super.loadlUrl().